# Debugging Full text search in iManage Worksite

Tags: indexer, imanage, worksite-sdk, hp-idol-ondemand

I am creating different workspaces having different types of names containing special characters also sometimes. When I am trying to perform a Full text search nothing comes up in workspace results. Now, problem is how can I start with the debugging process?

What all things to consider during Troubleshooting this issue on both IDOL Indexer and iManage worksite?

Any suggestions? Really Appreciated.

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 0):

You can enable debugging logs for all interactions through the SDK by turning on middleware Logging - Basically these log the actions performed by iManage.dll. 
The log paths registry key will provide the location of the log. Any application using iManage.dll will spawn a new file based on it's process name (such as YOURAPP.txt, WINWORD.txt, OUTLOOK.txt, etc)

Create or set the following values in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Interwoven\WorkSite\8.0\Common`

```
Name: Middleware Log Path
Type: String
Value: C:\Temp

Name: Middleware Log Flags
Type: DWORD
Value: ffff
```

This will show you useful information but the best way to debug is to pare your search parameters right back to basics then slowly introduce more complex parameters. Workspace search requests are made up of both  `IManage.IManProfileSearchParameters` and `IManage.IManWorkspaceSearchParameters`
and I've found that depending on the data sometimes you'll need to search only with the `IManProfileSearchParameters` and leave `IManWorkspaceSearchParameters` as default empty parameters.